# User posted answer after it was closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I just happened to see the question [Is it okay to whistle while at the office?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/98493/is-it-okay-to-whistle-while-at-the-office) and noticed that [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/98509/16983) was posted 32 minutes ago. However, the question was put on hold ***53 minutes ago***. How is this possible? Shouldn't putting a question on hold prevent any new answers being posted?

Comment: at MSE they say it's sometimes possible: [How was this answer posted after this question was closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91928/165773)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears this question was answered over [on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed/91928#91928) (h/t [@gnat](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/users/168/gnat))

> If a question is closed while you're answering on the full version of the site, you will receive a notification that the question was closed and the 'Post Your Answer' button will be disabled. However, this is only a client-side restriction, so it is possible in some cases that this process fails.
>
> When it does, the backend allows for a grace period of around four hours (previously there was no time limit). Presumably the client-side restriction did fail in this case, and since the answer was "in-flight", as Jeff describes it, the server accepted it despite the question already having been closed.